# Why spin manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, fermions, spinors

In physics people usually work with [spin manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure): this is quite deep and elaborate mathematical notion therefore I would like to ask: what is the reason to consider spin manifolds in physics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Physics considers spin manifolds because in quantum field theory [fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion) are described by spinor fields, which are formalized as sections of a [spinor bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor_bundle).

A relativistic spinor in $d$ dimensions should be a section of a Lorentzian $\mathrm{Spin}(d-1,1)$-bundle rather than the standard Riemannian spinor bundle, but the Riemannian spin manifolds find frequent use in models with extra dimensions, such as string theory or more general settings in which Kaluza-Klein reduction is necessary, as well as when treating the Euclidean ("[Wick-rotated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation)") case.